# Difference between AuthenticationStatus.Canceled and AuthenticationStatus.Failed

Tags: dotnetopenauth

What is the difference between `AuthenticationStatus.Canceled` and `AuthenticationStatus.Failed` in dotnetopenauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the metadata in `DotNetOpenAuth.dll`, the enumerations are described as:

> *AuthenticationStatus.Canceled*: The authentication was canceled by the user agent while at the provider.
>
> *AuthenticationStatus.Failed*: The authentication failed because an error was detected in the OpenId communication.

This should be shown by Visual Studio's intellisense (if you're using VS). I obtained it from v3.4.5.10202 of the dll.